# how to write a query to get records with n consecutive dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with date, hours and job id columns.  When we run our payroll, each worker has an entry with their hours worked for that week and the date is the period ending for the week.  So you'd see data something like...

```
Job Id  Hours   Week Ending Date
1       40      10/25/19
2       40      10/25/19
3       0       10/25/19
1       40      10/18/19
2       40      10/18/19
3       0       10/18/19
1       40      10/21/19
2       40      10/21/19
3       40      10/21/19
```

Notice that for job id 3, we have 2 week endings in a row with 0 hours.  I need to write a query that return that jobid - where there are 2+ consecutive weeks with 0 hours.  Any idea how to write this query?

Comment: which version of sql server?

Comment: version 14.0.3035.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where t.[Hours] = 0
and exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where [Job Id] = t.[Job Id] and [Hours] = 0 
  and abs(datediff(day, [WeekEndingDate], t.[WeekEndingDate])) = 7
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5d2e6e512be6c4966a6098925c7b94cd).
Results:

```
> Job Id | Hours | WeekEndingDate     
> -----: | ----: | :----------
>      3 |     0 | 25/10/2019 
>      3 |     0 | 18/10/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` or `lead()`:

```
select distinct job_id
from (select t.*,
             lead(hours) over (partition by job_id order by week_ending_date) as next_hours
      from t
     ) t
where hours = 0 and next_hours = 0;
```

The above formally answers your question of getting such job ids.  You might want to select information about which weeks as well.

Comment: Thanks, but this is giving me jobs with a single entry.  I'm looking for at least 2 consecutive weeks with 0 hours.  forpas answer above worked.

Comment: @geoffswartz . . . This should only give at least two weeks -- unless you have duplicate entries for a job in one week.  Are you sure you have implemented it correctly?  Do you understand what `lead()` does?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you one record for each period where there are 0 hours worked.

```sql
select
    a.[job id]
,   max(a.number_of_weeks) as number_of_weeks
from (
    select
        [job id]
    ,   [hours]
    ,   [Week Ending Date]
    ,   sum([hours]) over (partition by [job id], [hours] order by [job id], [Week Ending Date] desc ) as hour_count
    ,   row_number() over (partition by [job id], [hours] order by [job id], [Week Ending Date] desc ) as number_of_weeks
    from jobs
    ) as a
where a.hour_count = 0
group by a.[job id]
having MAX(a.number_of_weeks) > 1
```